# Rule-based classification not working on QGIS

Tags: qgis

I'm following the official QGIS tutorial on the QGIS website and I'm trying to create a rule-based classification as in the tutorial and I've followed the same steps as they have but it's simply not working. The whole polygons in the file I'm trying to classify only changes color to that of the default (no filter) criterion. I've attached some pictures here. The red arrow on the first picture points to the default criterion I mentioned earlier. What am I doing wrong? [image: image of my screen and problem][image: Image of what I'm supposed to get as in the tutorial]

Comment: Maybe that filter is on top of the other features, obscuring them - try turning it off for a second to see what's underneath.

Comment: Seems obvious but have you clicked Apply?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This may just be a matter of the font you are using, but in your screenshot it looks like you are using some kind of accent (e.g. ´) instead of the normal apostrophe (').

The first statement correctly should be:

```
"name" = 'Swellendam'
```

While editing a rule it is also possible to use the 'Test' button to determine if your rule returns some elements from the data or if there is any error in the filter statement.

Comment: I think it had to do with the kind of apostrophe. To save time I just copied the statement from the tutorial and pasted it into the expression string builder and didn't really notice that. Thanks a lot. I changed it to the normal (')  and it worked just fine.